Why are SOL tokens being sent to an off-curve address?
I saw someone on the Solana blockchain send three SOL tokens to the same off-curce address at different times. I know that off-curce is an abnormal transaction address. I am not a developer, and from a user transaction perspective, I don’t understand what the general purpose of doing this is?

Off-curve addresses are still usable.
They just don't have a Private Key and cannot be used to create signatures.
They are used by programs such as the Squads Multisig and Smart Accounts.
